# Insert a byte array into sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to insert an sql query that take a binary array into sql server but it's not working

```
public static void UpdateImage(int imageid, byte [] binaryData)
{
    string query = "Update images set IMAGE_BINARIES="+binaryData+" where IMAGE_ID="+imageid;
    new SQLHelper(SQLHelper.ConnectionStrings.KernelAccountConnectionString).Insert(query);

}
```

`IMAGE_BINARIES` is of type `varbinary(max)`

Comment: You may have a look at MSDN using [SQLParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx)!!

Comment: +1 Why duplicated questions always pop out before "the only right" questions in search engines? I don't know, but this one helped me for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this sample:

```
        public static void LogActivity( byte[] data)
        {

                var connection =
                    new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LogConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                var command = new SqlCommand { Connection = connection, CommandType = CommandType.Text };
                try
                {
                    command.CommandText = @"
insert into Logs (Data)
values ( @data)
";
                    command.Parameters.Add("@data", SqlDbType.VarBinary, data.Length).Value = data;
                    connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection.Close();
                    connection.Dispose();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log(ex);
                }

    }
```

Comment: Quite good dample, but you'd better to use stored procedures for create / update logic